# Streaming USB from a camera in Linux

Tags: linux, video

Is it possible to capture a USB audio/video stream from a *Sony Handycam DCR HC30E/S* on Linux?

All solutions I've seen so far advertise FireWire, *e.g.* [this Ubuntu forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=533835).

Comment: Your camera's got a FireWire interface (i.LINK). I think getting a FireWire interface might be easier.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Kino](http://kinodv.org/).  Should be in your linux's distro.

Answer (score 1):

i use my webcam with .. [mencoder / mplayer](http://mplayerhq.hu):

http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Webcam

Answer (score 0):

If your interest is for monitoring for surveillance purposes, I suggestion [Motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/twiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome). Nice package that can be configured to detect motion and save the video to disk each time it detects it. Has a lot to offer for monitoring, and runs as a daemon with no graphical interface, will also take stills.